# Checking a dynamically generated input ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a check list of checkbox that are generated like this:

```
@foreach($documents as $PDF)
<input {{$PDF->problem != 0 ? "disabled" : ""}}type="checkbox"
        id="mail_{{$PDF->id}}" value="{{$PDF->id}}"
          name="email[]"
          >

<input type="checkbox"
         id="post_{{$PDF->id}}" value="{{$PDF->id}}"
          name="post[]"
          >
@endforeach
```

When you click on any of these checkbox, a jQuery function should be called that will use the value of the clicked checkbox.

I am having troubles calling the function only when these 2 generated checkboxes are clicked.

There are, however, more inputs and checkbox in the page so something like `$(document).delegate('input', 'click', function (event)` is out of question.

There sure must be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a common CSS class to these elements

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="post_{{$PDF->id}}"
```

Then use a selector to target them

```
$(document).delegate('.checkbox:checkbox', 'click', function (event)...
```

---

Note `.delegate()` is depreciated in the favour of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

So changes code as

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox:checkbox', function (event)...
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performance.